# Can we have implicitly typed members?

Tags: type-systems

[Implicit typing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) in languages like C# permits compile-time type checks without necessarily referring "directly" to a target class:

```
var toy = SantasWorkshop.Build();
toy.amuse();
```

In this scenario, we don't need to know what type of `toy` it is. And yet, we'll still know *at compile-time* whether our `toy` fails to `amuse()`.

However, this is limited to the local scope. If we want to put that `toy` into a `Stocking` and retain the compile-time checks, we need to know something about it at compile time -- other than it's ability to `amuse()`. E.g., this is illegal:

```
class Stocking {
  List<var> toys;
  public void add(var toy) {
    toys.add(toy);
  }
}
```

If we're willing to sacrifice on the compile-time check, languages like C# allow us to use [dynamic typing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx):

```
class QuestionableLookingStocking {
  List<dynamic> toysIHope;
  public void add(dynamic toyIHope) {
    toysIHope.add(toyIHope);
  }
}
```

But, this will allow us to add objects to a `QuestionableLookingStocking` that may not actually `amuse()`. And we won't know about it until someone adds `Coal` at runtime.

```
class Coal {
  public ChristmasMood ruinChristmas() {
    return new SadChristmas();
  }
}
```

**Would it be logically possible and feasible for implicit typing to be extended to members?** I.e., is there any reason the compiler couldn't complain if someone tries to `Stocking.add()` an object that doesn't support the operations required by all references to `Stocking.toys[n]`?

**Are there patterns that could simulate implicit member types?**

Comment: I don't know if they go all the way, but languages in the ML family (ML, OCaml, F#) do much, much heavier implicit typing than C#. The inputs to functions are also typically implicitly typed. I don't think it extends as far as "class members" (or records, as it were),

Comment: Look however at Ocaml type system ; it has a particular typing for objects.

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/612689

Comment: This would be inherently impossible as you might not have the code available.  What happens when the information you need is in another .DLL for which you don't have the source?

Comment: @LorenPechtel If you can flesh that out a little, "It's impossible" is a totally legitimate answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate all of this in C# using generics.

This code is legal:

```
class Stocking<T> {
  List<T> toys;
  public void add(T toy) {
    toys.add(toy);
  }
}
```

And I'm pretty sure it fulfills all of your established objectives: you get compile-time type safety over all of your members, and every toy is an object that supports the operations required by all references to `Stocking.toys`.

Naturally, you're not going to get any additional capabilities from each toy beyond what is already provided by type `T`, which is probably what you're really after.  So how about trying something like this:

```
public class Toy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Truck: Toy
{
    public void Dump()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dumping");
    }
}

public class Stocking<T>
{
    List<T> toys = new List<T>();
    public void Add(T toy)
    {
        toys.Add(toy);
    }
    public T Get(int index)
    {
        return toys[index];
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new Stocking<Toy>();
        var t = new Truck() { Name = "Tonka" };

        s.Add(t);
        var toy = s.Get(0);

        // Generic Toy behavior
        Console.WriteLine(toy.Name);

        // Truck-specific behavior
        if (toy is Truck)
        {
            (toy as Truck).Dump();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This code outputs

```
Tonka
Dumping
```

Which is exactly what you would expect.

Comment: But this is not what the OP asked for, as it's simply moving the explicit type definition from one place to another.

Comment: The `var` is still there; it's just implied.  I've added a couple more lines of code in the `Main` method to clarify.

Comment: Let me clarify: `var` let's me operate as though I'm using an interface that doesn't actually exist anywhere. Generics require that A) an interface or base class actually exists, and B) everything that *could* go into the `Stocking` implements it *explicitly*. I'm skeptical (but hopeful) that a trick or pattern exists, or that it's a potential language feature, that my "anonymous pseudo-interface" could *actually* be constituted at compile-time, and enforced in a manner that doesn't require explicit inheritance.

Comment: In C#, you can't enforce at compile time what isn't declared at compile time.  Haskell might do this; it's type system is much more powerful than the C# type system; I suggest you look there.  In any case, I consider the ability to check the supertype at runtime a reasonable compromise; since you really have no idea what `SantasWorkshop.Build()` might return, the only way to know that at compile time is to declare a concrete return type (i.e. `Toy`).

Comment: In any case, the way you solve this problem in C# is to defer type-checking to runtime (which is what `dynamic` does), so your goal (of checking at compile time that which is not declared at compile time) is pretty much at odds with the design of the language.

Comment: Also, to clarify: type inference doesn't use an *implied interface* that doesn't actually exist; it uses an *actual, declared "interface."*  What happens is that the compiler works out the type of the expression declared on the right-hand side of the equals sign, and that's the type of the object that is assigned to the `var` variable.  `var` doesn't even exist in the compiled IL.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep. I understand it's not *actually* an anonymous type. But, it let's *the programmer* operate *as though* there's an anonymous pseudo-interface -- at least to an extent. In other words, when I declare a variable with `var`, the compiler (and the IDE) will complain if there's a mismatch between the inferred type and how I go on to use the variable. But, as long as there *isn't* a mismatch, the inferred type can be "anything" that can `amuse().` I don't have to know what it is. And, I can change it without forcing the new inferred class to implement a complete explicit interface.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's certainly good to point out though, that `var` has limitations beyond using it as a member "type." For example, `var` doesn't help if `SantasWorkshop.Build()` doesn't really know what type it returns. But, what you do gain from using the `var` "pseudo-type" is the ability to change `SantasWorkshop.Build()`'s contract without touching code that *calls* it, provided that the new contract is compatible with how the old contract is *actually used.*

Comment: @svidgen: `SantasWorkshop.Build()` *always* knows what type it returns, unless you're referring to a possible supertype.  [You can't return an anonymous type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10073319/102937) from a method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, I had `Object` in mind when I typed it. But, I believe methods can also return `dynamic` ... can't they?

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Robert Harvey's answer:

You don't need to stop at Toy.

```
public class Possession
{
    public String Name {get; set;}

    public abstract void Use();
}

public class Toy : Possession
{
    public void Amuse()
    {
        Use();
    }
}

public class Truck : Toy
{
}

public class Dumptruck : Truck
{
    public override void Use()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dumping");
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public List<Possession> Owns;
    public List<Toy> Stocking;

    public void AddToStocking(Possession Item)
    {
        if (Item is Toy)
            Stocking.Add(Item);
        else
            throw new GrinchException($"{Item.Name} is not a toy, why are you trying to put it in {Name}'s stocking?");
    }
}
```